# PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column "score" is of type integer but expression is of type text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my code:

```
    factors.each do |f|
      factor_score_var = "factorScore_#{f.id}"
      params['score'] = params[factor_score_var]
      new_scorecard.scorecard_scores.create(params.permit(:score))
    end
```

Here is the error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column "score" is of type integer but expression is of type text at character 98 HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I have tried casting the score param with 'to_i' etc.. :

```
params['score'] = params[factor_score_var].to_i
```

But I just keep getting the same error.

I have confirmed that :score is holding a number (I still get this error if I set the var to a number manually), but I still get this error.

Database is Postgress.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Jason

=====================

Here is the full error message:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column "score" is of type integer but expression is of type text at character 98 HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. : INSERT INTO "scorecard_scores" ("created_at", "score", "scorecard_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

Here is the full trace:

```
    activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:780:in `get_last_result'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:780:in `exec_cache'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:139:in `block in exec_query'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:183:in `exec_insert'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:96:in `insert'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:76:in `insert'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:498:in `create_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:78:in `create_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:303:in `block in create_record'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__506216057516292564__create__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:303:in `create_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:466:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__506216057516292564__save__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:200:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:39:in `insert_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:463:in `block (2 levels) in create_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:367:in `add_to_target'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:461:in `block in create_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:152:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:151:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:460:in `create_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:121:in `create'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:260:in `create'
app/controllers/scorecard_controller.rb:17:in `block in create'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
app/controllers/scorecard_controller.rb:14:in `create'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__2842308223683398234__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2239646144333399607__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: I tried changing the columg type to text, and it inserts the number fine as required.  But I need this column to be an integer.  When I change it to integer, I get this error.  So I do know that it is inserting a number, but it looks like rails is trying to insert it as a string.  How do I get rails to insert it as an integer?

Comment: Hi mu is too short, have added full error and trace to the post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found the problem.

When I originally created the migration, this field was type text.  I then did db:rollback and re-ran it with this field being an integer. Event though I reran the migration, rails must have still been treating it as a text.

All I needed to do was restart the rails server and all worked fine.

Comment: You can accept your own answers BTW, I think you have to wait 24 hours though. I'm guessing that you missed a "restart the rails server" step somewhere, that could lead to your model caching the old version of the table so it would still think that `score` was a string even though the database migration changed it to a number. AR reads the table schema (including column types) when it starts up.

Comment: Yes.. one of those 'doh' moments.. learning the hard way.. I spent hours scratching my head on that one.. can't believe it didn't occur to me to restart server.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks so much for posting the solution after you figured it out. I also would have been head scratching for hours had I not found your post.